# correlation between categorical(ordinal) and discrete(continuous) value

Tags: correlation

I am doing my bi variate analysis  but right now looking to see the correlation between  my atributes

some are categorical 5 levels and others amount of money.

how can I see the correlation between them ?

do I have to create class for my money amount?

Answer (score 0):

You can juse bin them to numerical bins [1 - 5] as long as you are sure you're doing this to ordinal variables and not nominal ones. Bivariate analysis should be easier for you.

If you still want to see how to get correlation of categorical variables vs continuous , i suggest you read more about [Chi-square test](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html) and [Analysis of variance ( ANOVA )](https://pythonfordatascience.org/anova-python/)